# Show that $\mathfrak{A}$ is a sigma algebra only if $\Omega$ is finite.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, set-theory

> Given that $\Omega\neq \emptyset $ and $\mathfrak{A}= \{ A \subseteq \Omega :A \text{ is finite or $$}A ^c \text{ is finite}\}.$ Show that $\mathfrak{A}$ is a sigma algebra only if $\Omega$ is finite.

I'm having trouble proving this straightforward statement. My idea was to assume $\Omega$ is infinite and then observe some cases. First case is when $A$ is finite and $A^c$ is infinite, if this is the case then $\mathfrak{A}$ can't be a sigma algebra because then it couldn't be closed under complementation considering $\mathfrak{A}= A\subsetneq A^c \implies A^c\notin \mathfrak{A}$. I think this is a strong argument but I'm not sure about the second case when $A$ is infinite and $A^c$ is finite. $\mathfrak{A}=A \subseteq\Omega $ with $\bigcup^{\infty}{A_n}\in\mathfrak{A} \implies \bigcup^{\infty}{}{\big((A_n)^c\big)} \in \mathfrak{A}$ which is a contradiction because not every $A_n$ would have its complement in $\mathfrak{A}$ in this case.

I hope someone can check my work and if wrong give a helping hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\Omega$ is infinite and $\mathfrak{U}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$.

If $\Omega$ were infinite, its cardinality is at least $\aleph_{0} = \text{card}(\mathbb{N})$.

Then it would be possible to enumerate a subset of it labeled as follows:
\begin{align*}
W = \{\omega_{0}, \omega_{1},\omega_{2},\omega_{3},\ldots\}
\end{align*}

Observe that each $W_{n} = \{\omega_{n}\}$ is finite.

Due to the fact that $\mathfrak{U}$ is closed under countable union, it would result that
\begin{align*}
P = \bigcup_{n\geq 1}W_{2n-1} = \{\omega_{1},\omega_{3},\omega_{5},\ldots\}
\end{align*}
is an element of $\mathfrak{U}$. But this leads to a contradiction, because neither $P$ nor $P^{c}$ is finite:
\begin{align*}
\text{card}(P^{c}) \geq \text{card}\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 0}W_{2n}\right) = \text{card}(\{\omega_{0},\omega_{2},\omega_{4},\ldots\}) = \aleph_{0}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!